# How to seal gazebo post bases already installed?

Tags: outdoor, waterproofing, patio, sealing

First time homeowner as of this week. During our inspection, inspector raised concerns over the rot occurring at the base of the posts on the gazebo located on our back porch. He recommended sealing using epoxy, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this.

The porch/patio is made from a highly porous, fixed-rubber-gravel type of material (I'm not sure what it's called—if you know what I'm talking about, let me know what it's called). I'm assuming that the posts have been installed in a concrete base, but I don't know for certain. Here are my questions:

- Can I dump epoxy along the base of each post to seal this? Would this be enough to prevent further damage?
- Should I caulk along each post, where the post meets the porch material, to support the epoxy in preventing water damage?
- Should I get a contractor to take a look at it?

My concern with the epoxy is that, due to the porous nature of the porch material, it would just seep outward from the post base rather than cling to the base to provide a watertight seal.

Sorry for the poor photos, we don't move in for another two days—these are from the inspection.

[image: Post rot]
[image: Porch 1]
[image: Porch 2]

Comment: I expect he means use something like Ronseal Wet Rot Wood Hardener. A resin based preservative which soaks into wood

Comment: @Tragamor Thanks. Do you know if I would need to remove the posts entirely for this? Or can I just pour the hardener down the sides at the base?

Comment: You paint it on in coats. It'll soak in and you can add a few coats over a few minutes. Once it dries it'll seal.

Comment: @Tragamor Awesome, I'll pick some up tonight. Thanks for the help